# Postfix notation is changing precedence of parentheses in evalution

Tags: math, data-structures, stack, complexity-theory, theory

In a/b*(c+(d-e)) Infix notation (d-e) will be evaluated first but if we convert it into Post-fix ab/cde-+* then ab/ will be evaluated first.

why ab/ is evaluating first in post-fix instead of d-e?

Comment: Because this is not directly related to programming, perhaps this would be better on [math.se] (also add an actual question instead of just an statement)

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication and division are [left-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity), meaning they are evaluated from left to right. Since *a* and *b* are terminals (no further evaluation needs to be done), `ab/` is ready to be evaluated. Once we get to the last term, `c+(d-e)`, we need to delve deeper and only then do we evaluate `de-`.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about "precedence" (a concept which is designed to disambiguate infix notation hence not really applicable to postfix notation) you really seem to mean "order of operations", which is a broader notion.

One thing to realize is that the order of operations taught in elementary school (often with the pneumonic PEMDAS) isn't necessarily the order of operations that a computer will use when evaluating an expression like `a/b*(c+(d-e))`. Using PEMDAS, you would first calculate `d-e` then `c+(d-e)` etc., which *is* a different order than that implicit in `ab/cde-+*`. But, it is interesting to note that many programming languages will in fact evaluate `a/b*(c+(d-e))` by using the order of `ab/cde-+*` rather than by a naive implementation of PEMDAS. As an example, if in Python you import the module [dis](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html) and evaluate `dis.dis("a/b*(c+(d-e))")` to disassemble `a/b*(c+(d-e))` into Python byte code you get:

```
          0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
          2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
          4 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
          6 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
          8 LOAD_NAME                3 (d)
         10 LOAD_NAME                4 (e)
         12 BINARY_SUBTRACT
         14 BINARY_ADD
         16 BINARY_MULTIPLY
         18 RETURN_VALUE
```

which is easily seen to be exactly the same order of operations as `ab/cde-+*`. In fact, this postfix notation can be thought of as shorthand for the stack-based computation that Python uses when it evaluates `a/b*(c+(d-e))`

Comment: That's a generous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both evaluation orders execute the same operations with the same arguments and produce the same result, so in that sense the difference doesn't matter.

There are differences that matter, though.  The grade-school arithmetic order is never used when infix expressions are evaluated in practice, because:

1. It requires more intermediate results to be stored.  (a+b)*(c+d)*(e+f)*(g+h) requires 4 intermediate sums to be stored in grade-school order, but only 2 in the usual order.
2. It's actually more complicated to implement the grade-school order in most cases; and
3. When sub-expressions have side-effects, the order becomes important and the usual order is easier for programmers to reason about.